# Adding Records using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know

i am currentlydeveloping a program and i need my users to be able to press the (+) to add a new record to the table, or alternitivly if it is the last record in the table and the user presses the down arrow key it should add a new row.

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: By "record", do you mean a tr element in an html table, or a record in a database table? Please show what you have so far and explain where you're getting stuck - don't just state your requirements and expect people to implement the whole thing from scratch. Meanwhile a hint: you probably want to handle the `keyup` event. And if "(+)" means the actual key (as compared to some button on-screen), what if they want to enter a "+" character?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add html you can use jquery,to add a row in the table at last position use this

```
$('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

First You should add a Addnew button or row, Then write this code to onclick

```
$("#hidden_add_form").show();
```

To post the form using jquery

```
$("#hidden_add_form").submit(function(){
    $.post("save.php",$("#hidden_add_form").serialize(),function(){
          alert('saved');
     })
}
```